# PHP json automatically sorting in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, json

I am getting **JSON** from **PHP** and using it in JavaScript to put Select Box option value.
But when i am putting my **PHP** side **JSON** in **JavaScript** it is sorting automatically.

This should not be done.

Actually i am using this **JSON** as HTML select Box option value
and i need my original data as coming From PHP side.

**JSON Coming from PHP side:**

**PHP CODE:**

```
$optionJSON= json_encode($optionValues);
```

**Result:**

```
{
    "0":"Select",
    "37":"Abc",
    "47":"DEF",
    "359":"GHI",
    "182":"JKL",
    "360":"MNO",
    "183":"PQR",
    "320":"STU",
    "38":"VWX",
    "80":"YZA"
}
```

**Showing In browser console and same order in Select Box Option value.**

```
{
    "0": "Select",
    "37": "Abc",
    "38": "VWX",
    "47": "DEF",
    "80": "YZA",
    "182": "JKL",
    "183": "PQR",
    "320": "STU",
    "359": "GHI",
    "360": "MNO"
}
```

Comment: This is not regulated behaviour by **ECMA**. You can not rely on having this browser-independent. %)p

Comment: The order of elements in an object is not specified, and there's no way to control it. If you want the values to stay in a particular order, use an array.

Comment: @Barmar Please can you give me a example

Answer (score 1):

You pass a JSON object around, within the object instance you cannot rely on the order of the elements.

Use an array instead or give each object some kind of sort order and sort the list on the client...

```
var x = [
  {"0":"Select"},
  {"37":"Abc"},
  {"47":"DEF"},
  {"359":"GHI"},
  {"38":"VWX"}
];
```

Comment: The JSON comes from PHP, so it would be better to show the PHP syntax of this data.

Answer (score 1):

Return an array like this:

```
$result = array(
    array('value' => 0, 'text' => 'Select'),
    array('value' => 37, 'text' => 'Abc'),
    array('value' => 47, 'text' => 'DEF'),
    array('value' => 359, 'text' => 'GHI'),
    array('value' => 182, 'text' => 'JKL'),
    array('value' => 360, 'text' => 'MNO'),
    array('value' => 183, 'text' => 'PQR'),
    array('value' => 320, 'text' => 'STU'),
    array('value' => 38, 'text' => 'VWX'),
    array('value' => 80, 'text' => 'YZA')
);
echo json_encode($result);
```

When I do this, the output is:

```
[{"value":0,"text":"Select"},{"value":37,"text":"Abc"},{"value":47,"text":"DEF"},{"value":359,"text":"GHI"},{"value":182,"text":"JKL"},{"value":360,"text":"MNO"},{"value":183,"text":"PQR"},{"value":320,"text":"STU"},{"value":38,"text":"VWX"},{"value":80,"text":"YZA"}]
```

When I copy that to Javascript and use `JSON.parse()`, the result is in the desired order. See http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/8ypzvhku/1/

Comment: Sorry Mr. Barmar Problem is same.. :(